# GRanges - how to get a score vector per base (R / Bioinformatics)

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am learning the GRanges library (Bioconductor) in R to work with my genomic data.

```
my GRange looks like:
chrI [1, 10] * | 100
chrI [11, 20] * | 200
```

I would like to get a vector with scores of GRange length [1:20] (per base resolution), but instead I always get a score per line in the GRange.

```
myvec <- mygrange$score   # return [100, 200]
myvec <- coverage(mygrange, weight="score")   # return [100, 200]
myvec <- as.vector(mcols(mygrange)$score)   # return [100, 200]
```

...
all results return a vector with length 2 instead of 20.

Could anyone, please, explain how to get a vector with score data per base resolution?

Comment: You might get more/good responses for this on the new bioinformatics StackExchange website: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please delete this post, it is answered at bio SE. https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/874/131

Answer (score 1):

```
> gr = GRanges(c("chrI", "chrI"), IRanges(start=c(1, 11), width=c(10, 10)), mcols=data.frame(score=c(100, 200)))
> gr
GRanges object with 2 ranges and 1 metadata column:
      seqnames    ranges strand | mcols.score
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> |   <numeric>
  [1]     chrI  [ 1, 10]      * |         100
  [2]     chrI  [11, 20]      * |         200
  -------
  seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
> vec <- rep(gr$mcols.score, width(gr))
> vec
 [1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200
```